# ¿Hacer una condición para cuando se cierra un JFrame?

Tags: java

para meterlos en contexto tengo un proyecto que inicia con un JFrame, el cual tiene una tabla y en la tabla tiene unas cuantas filas (mismas que trae en una base de datos), cada fila tiene 2 botones, uno que finaliza la alarma y otra que la apaga, ya que estas filas vienen con una alarma audible, anexo foto:
[image: TABLA]

El funcionamiento es muy básico, para poder apagar la alarma audible basta con dar clic en todos los botones de apagar alarma, en el ejemplo solo se muestra una fila, pero si hubiera 5 filas es necesario presionar los 5 botones para apagar la alarma, seguido tenemos el botón de finalizar alarma, este botón tiene la función de primero preguntarnos si queremos finalizar la alarma, y luego nos muestra otro JFrame que funciona como modal. Adjunto fotos:
[image: Finalizar alarma]
[image: Modal]

Por lógica, el usuario ya tendría que haber apagado la alarma antes de finalizarla, pero en casa de que la alarma no se encuentre apagada y el usuario use el botón finalizar, nos saldrá un mensaje preguntándonos si queremos apagar la alarma antes.
Ahora, en caso de que la alarma este apagada y el usuario de en finalizar la alarma y dentro de la ventana que le pregunta si desea finalizar la alarma el usuario use el botón "NO o "CANCELAR" en lugar de usar al botón "SI" además de el modal no aparecerá, la alarma tendrá que encenderse de nuevo, cosa que resolví con una condición, adjunto código:

```
  int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Desea finalizar la alarma?", "FINALIZAR ALARMA", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        modal(modelIndex);//Función que nos muestra el modal
                    

                } else {/*Si la persona usa otra opción que no sea "SI" entonces encedemos la alarma*/
                    {
                        JButton alarma = null;
                        int idtabla = Integer.parseInt(getIdTabla());/*Primero verificamos que la alarma si se
                                                                        Encuentra apagada*/
                        if (this.buscarLista(idtabla)) {

                            String mensaje = "Se ha detenido la alarma del registro con fecha:  " + getFechaTabla()
                                    + "  Del centro:  " + getCentroTabla() + "  Caja:  " + getCajaTabla() + "  Con el ID:  " + getIdTabla();

                            try {
                                this.reactivaciónAlarmas(mensaje, alarma, row, column, idtabla);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                            System.out.println("ESTA ALARMA SE ENCUENTRA APAGADA, VAMOS A ENCENDERLA DE NUEVO!");

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Les explico, al momento de que sale el mensaje: ¿DESAE FINALIZAR LA ALRMA? y el usuario usa el botón si entonces se ejecuta la función que muestra el modal, en caso contrario, la alarma se activa de nuevo (En caso de que esta se encuentre desactivada).

Ok, hasta aquí todo bien, el problema lo tengo cuando el usuario usa el botón de "SI" y aparece el modal, ya que si el usuario cierra la ventana del modal, necesito reactivar la alarma, por lo que quiero crear una condición en donde si se cierra la ventana la alarma se active de nuevo, ejemplo:

```
 if(moda == cerrado){
 ActivaciónAlarmas();
 }
```

crear una condición que me diga: si usas el botón "X" que cierra la ventana del modal, entonces reactiva esa alarma.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, porque no se ni por donde comenzar a crear esta función, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo para eso debes programar el evento windowCLosing del tu modal

```
 modal.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Reactivando alarma...");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Amigo, me has salvado, jaja, enserio me encuentro a full agradecido contigo!, espero algún día poder devolverte el favor!.